# RAID1 LVM, XEN and flashcache

Tags: xen, lvm, raid1, flashcache

I am regarding to question: [Improving IO with FlashCache](https://serverfault.com/questions/449088/improving-io-with-flashcache)

I have setup a RAID1 (*/dev/md0*) LVM (*/dev/vg_xen*) and executed following command:

```
flashcache_create -p thru flashcache0 /dev/sdc /dev/md0
```

Then I started a XEN PV guest, which uses */dev/vg_xen/vm0* as hard disk. After using it a while

```
cat /proc/flashcache/sdc\+md0/flashcache_stats
```

shows me

```
reads=0 writes=0
```

So, it does not work. What did I do wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should make sure that your LVM is using the `/dev/mapper/flashcache0` device as its physical volume instead of using /dev/md0 directly (in the latter case flashcache would not be involved in the I/O code path at all).

See http://sf-alpha.bjgang.org/wordpress/2012/11/flashcache-initscripts/ for a handy script on how to set this up, if you have not done so yet. The basic outline would be:

1. exclude /dev/md0 from being detected through LVM by adding `filter = [ "r|/dev/md0|" ]` and commenting out or removing `filter = [ "a/.*/" ]` (if present) from the `devices{}` section of your `/etc/lvm/lvm.conf`
2. use the `flashcache_create` (or `flashcache_load` if using write-back caching mode) command to create your flashcache-backed device
3. run `vgscan` to discover your volume group and activate it by issuing `vgchange -ay vg_xen`

For details on flashcache configuration, refer to the [admin guide](https://github.com/facebook/flashcache/blob/master/doc/flashcache-sa-guide.txt) which came with your flashcache download.

Comment: *flashcache_load : Load an existing writeback cache volume.*, but I am not using a writeback cache volume.

Comment: @JuanHynix My fault. It appears you have not reconfigured your LVM to be backed by the flashcache-created device, could you check that?

Comment: Yes. You are right. I did not reconfigured it. I will try your new advice.

Comment: I did it again today. Now it works like you said. Thanks.